# How can I speedup Redshift COPY from S3 Parquet files for 91Gb of data?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have 91gb of Parquet files (10.6 billion rows) that I need to copy into a Redshift table. The number of files is roughly 220,000. From my estimates of loading a few files and checking the execution time, it will take 4 hours to load all the data. Is there a way to get that time down significantly?
The Node Type is ra3.4xlarge and node count is 4.

I set the COPY options

```
COMPUPDATE OFF
STATUPDATE OFF
```

I also ran

```
VACUUM
```

and

```
ANALYSE
```

The parquet file's columns are organized exactly in the order that they need to be inserted into the table.

Comment: Did you check the recommendations given by AWS? One attempt would be to decrease the number of parquet files if possible, which seems to be around half a megabyte only. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_best-practices-use-multiple-files.html

Answer (score 4):

Your files are too small.  At least 1MB file size is AWS' recommendation and in my experience anything less than 200K is noticeably slow.  This is a limitation of S3 more than Redshift.

You see S3 as an object store takes time to look-up and find a file in its vast cluster of computers.  This takes between .5 and .75 second to perform and with 220K files these half seconds add up.

It may be possible that your estimate is off.  When you performed your speed test on a few files did you try to load enough files at once such that you maxed out the parallelism between Redshift and S3?  Redshift will distribute the work of loading files from S3 to all the slices in the cluster and these slices will all pull from S3 in parallel.  So if you only tested with 1 or a few files you may not be seeing the parallelism that will happen when you do the full COPY.  So it may be better than you think even with these small-ish files.